# Nginx Rewrite Rule for the nested location

Tags: nginx, server, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have my domain config file setup for Nginx. I have set domain like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and I have all sub directory also inside that like basefolder/index.html, basefolder/abc1/signup/index.html, basefolder/abc2/signup/index.html, basefolder/signup/index.html etc as n number can be exists.

I can directly call them through domain/dir/ which will call the index.html file available in that directory. I have some specific query string set for the "signup" folders only like "www.example.com/signup/?query=a12seddf" or "www.example.com/abc1/signup/?query=a12seddf". I want to covert them to the path like "www.example.com/signup/a12seddf" or "www.example.com/abc1/signup/a12seddf". I tried with the rewrite rule but it works only if I give the whole location till the signup but I want to write the single rule which will work on all signup folder instead of writing the rewrite rule for all.

I tried below code but it won't work for me and giving 404 on accessing the beautify URL.

```
location ~* signup/ {
    rewrite ^/signup/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/?$ /signup/?query=$1 break;   
}
```

Please find the whole sample working config file given below with names example.com.conf in nginx/sites-enabled folder:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        root /var/www/html/sites/example.com;

        error_page 404 /error_404.html;
        location = /error_404.html {
                root /var/www/html;
                internal;
        }
        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
            expires 30d;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }
    rewrite ^/abc1/signup/(.*)$ /abc1/signup/index.html?_l=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/signup/(.*)$ /signup/index.html?_l=$1 last;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should show more of your configuration so that we can understand how it is supposed to work. And an example of the solution that was working for one folder only.

Comment: @RichardSmith I have attached the sample of working file demo in my updated question. Please let me know if you have any idea for this. Thanks.